# Equivalent Nested Loop Structure with Itertools

Tags: python, python-2.7, foreach, python-itertools

Python's succint syntax through its batteries allows verbose code line to be expressed in readable one liners. Consider the following examples

```
====================================================|
for a in range(3):                                  |
    for b in range(3):                              |
        for c in range(3):                          |
            print (a,b,c),                          |
-  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -|
for e in product(range(3), repeat=3):               |
    print e,                                        |
====================================================|
for a in range(3):                                  |
    for b in range(a , 3):                          |
        for c in range(b , 3):                      |
            print (a,b,c),                          |
-  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -|
for e in combinations_with_replacement(range(3), 3):|
    print e,                                        |
====================================================|
for a in range(3):                                  |
    for b in range(a + 1, 3):                       |
        for c in range(b + 1, 3):                   |
            print (a,b,c),                          |
-  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -|
for e in combinations(range(3), 3):                 |
    print e,                                        |
====================================================|
for a in range(3):                                  |
    for b in range(3):                              |
        for c in range(3):                          |
            if len(set([a,b,c])) == 3:              |
                print (a,b,c),                      |
-  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -|
for e in permutations(range(3)):                    |
    print e,                                        |
====================================================|
```

Of Late I ended up with a deep nested dependent Loop I was trying to express succinctly but failed

The structure of the loop would be as follows

```
for a in A():
    for b in B(a):
        for c in C(b):
            foo(a,b,c)
```

Can such structure be expressed in an equivalent itertools notation?

Comment: Just a note. This last loop in Prolog would be expressed as: `a(A), b(A, B), c(B, C)`. If you like playing with loops, play with Prolog.

Comment: do you use `a`, `b` (intermediate values) in the body of the innermost loop?

Comment: @liori: Prolog always enticed me but was never intelligent enough to learn artificial intelligence

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yes I do :-)

Answer (score 5):

There's no exact `itertools` solution, but a simple combination of `itertools` functions will suffice:

```
def chain_imap_accumulate(seq, f):
    def acc_f(x):
        for n in f(x[-1]):
            yield x + (n,)
    return chain.from_iterable(imap(acc_f, seq))

def accumulative_product(*generators):
    head, tail = generators[0], generators[1:]
    head = imap(tuple, head())
    return reduce(chain_imap_accumulate, tail, head)
```

A quick test. Definitions:

```
from itertools import chain, imap, izip
chain_ = chain.from_iterable

def A():
    yield 'A'
    yield 'B'

def B(x):
    yield int(x, 16)
    yield int(x, 16) + 1

def C(x):
    yield str(x) + 'Z'
    yield str(x) + 'Y'
```

And the result:

```
>>> list(accumulative_product(A, B, C))
[('A', 10, '10Z'), ('A', 10, '10Y'), 
 ('A', 11, '11Z'), ('A', 11, '11Y'), 
 ('B', 11, '11Z'), ('B', 11, '11Y'), 
 ('B', 12, '12Z'), ('B', 12, '12Y')]
```

Almost all the complexity comes from the accumulation of inputs, as a quick "derivation" of the above code shows. The *final* (`c`) values can be generated using just a couple of nested `itertools` constructs:

```
>>> list(chain_(imap(C, chain_(imap(B, (A()))))))
['10Z', '10Y', '11Z', '11Y', '11Z', '11Y', '12Z', '12Y']
```

This can be generalized with `reduce`. To work with `reduce`, `chain_imap` can't use the standard `imap` argument order. It has to be swapped:

```
def chain_imap(seq, f):
    return chain.from_iterable(imap(f, seq))
```

This gives the same results:

```
>>> list(reduce(chain_imap, [B, C], A()))
['10Z', '10Y', '11Z', '11Y', '11Z', '11Y', '12Z', '12Y']
```

The final task is accumulating the initial values, so that you have access to `a`, `b`, and `c`. This takes a bit of thought to get right, but the implementation is fairly simple -- we just have to convert `f` into a function that ignores all input values but the last, and appends new values to the full input:

```
def chain_imap_accumulate(seq, f):
    def acc_f(x):
        for n in f(x[-1]):
            yield x + (n,)
    return chain.from_iterable(imap(acc_f, seq))
```

This requires that the first inputs be wrapped in tuples, so we map `A` with `tuple`:

```
>>> list(reduce(chain_imap_accumulate, [B, C], imap(tuple, A())))
[('A', 10, '10Z'), ('A', 10, '10Y'), 
 ('A', 11, '11Z'), ('A', 11, '11Y'), 
 ('B', 11, '11Z'), ('B', 11, '11Y'), 
 ('B', 12, '12Z'), ('B', 12, '12Y')]
```

Rewrite the above for clarity, and the code at the top of this answer results.

By the way, `chain_imap_accumulate` can be rewritten a bit more tersely using a genex. This can be combined with a shorter version of `accumulative_product` for a very compact definition (if you're interested in that kind of thing). This also happens to eliminate the itertools dependency entirely:

```
def chain_map_accumulate(seq, f):
    return (x + (n,) for x in seq for n in f(x[-1]))

def accumulative_product2(*gens):
    return reduce(chain_map_accumulate, gens[1:], (tuple(x) for x in gens[0]()))
```

Comment: This hurts my brain, but is there a way to use 3.3's `itertools.accumulate` with its function parameter to simplify/complexify this?

Comment: I feel you're right that there must be a way to make that work. You might be able to use `accumulate` instead of `reduce`, and accumulate a sequence of `a`, `b`, and `c` values; but the number of `a` values would differ from the number of `b` values, which would differ from the number of `c` values. You'd then have to figure out how to redistribute the values into a flat sequence of `a, b, c` tuples. The challenge would be to do that elegantly...

Comment: From accumulate you would obtain something like --> `('A', 'B'), ((10, 11), (11, 12)), (('10Z', '10Y'), ('11Z', '11Y'), ('11Z', '11Y'), ('12Z', '12Y'))` I'm not sure this will be any cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

There is not, but you can make one:

```
def chainGang(steps, currentVars=None):
    thisOne = steps[0]
    if currentVars is None:
        for item in thisOne():
            for gang in chainGang(steps[1:], [item]):
                yield gang
    elif len(steps) == 1:       
        for item in thisOne(currentVars[-1]):
            yield currentVars + [item]
    else:
        for item in thisOne(currentVars[-1]):
            for gang in chainGang(steps[1:], currentVars + [item]):
                yield gang
```

And then:

```
>>> outer = lambda: ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
>>> middle = lambda letter: [letter, letter*2, letter*3]
>>> inner = lambda s: range(len(s)+1)
>>> for a in chainGang([outer, middle, inner]):
...     print a
[u'A', u'A', 0]
[u'A', u'A', 1]
[u'A', u'AA', 0]
[u'A', u'AA', 1]
[u'A', u'AA', 2]
[u'A', u'AAA', 0]
[u'A', u'AAA', 1]
[u'A', u'AAA', 2]
[u'A', u'AAA', 3]
[u'B', u'B', 0]
[u'B', u'B', 1]
[u'B', u'BB', 0]
[u'B', u'BB', 1]
[u'B', u'BB', 2]
[u'B', u'BBB', 0]
[u'B', u'BBB', 1]
[u'B', u'BBB', 2]
[u'B', u'BBB', 3]
[u'C', u'C', 0]
[u'C', u'C', 1]
[u'C', u'CC', 0]
[u'C', u'CC', 1]
[u'C', u'CC', 2]
[u'C', u'CCC', 0]
[u'C', u'CCC', 1]
[u'C', u'CCC', 2]
[u'C', u'CCC', 3]
[u'D', u'D', 0]
[u'D', u'D', 1]
[u'D', u'DD', 0]
[u'D', u'DD', 1]
[u'D', u'DD', 2]
[u'D', u'DDD', 0]
[u'D', u'DDD', 1]
[u'D', u'DDD', 2]
[u'D', u'DDD', 3]
```