# Itertools equivalent of nested loop "for x in xs: for y in ys..."

Tags: python, nested-loops, python-itertools

I have a nested loop to create all combinations in a set of conjugated verbs. The aim to to get all possible combinations of verb, person and tense, e.g. `[['to be', 'first person singular', 'future'],['to be', 'second person singular', 'future'], ...]`.

```
for v in verbs:
    for p in persons:
        for t in tenses:
            return [v, p, t]
```

Is there a way of reducing the nesting, perhaps using `itertools`?

Comment: related: [Equivalent Nested Loop Structure with Itertools](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15037175/4279)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
for v, p, t in itertools.product(verbs, persons, tenses):
    ...
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this task:

> Cartesian product of input iterables. Equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For example, product(A, B) returns the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in B).

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [7,8,9]
import itertools
for p in itertools.product(a,b,c):
    print(p)
```

The alternative would be a list comprehension expression:

```
for p in [(x,y,z) for x in a for y in b for z in c]:
    print(p)
```